# asp check all child nodes if parent is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Tree view control, that I am setting up; if a parent node is selected, then all of the child nodes will be selected as well.

I am trying to get this going on the server side, but with no luck. Can someone shed a little light.

Here is my code:

```
protected void tv_WLG_TreeNodeCheckChanged(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode tnParentNode = e.Node;
    foreach (TreeNode n in tnParentNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        n.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is a `new TreeNode();` instantly going to have `ChildNodes` on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant something like:

```
protected void tv_WLG_TreeNodeCheckChanged(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Node.Checked) 
    {
        var stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        stack.Push(e.Node);
        while (stack.Count > 0) 
        {
            var node = stack.Pop();
            node.Checked = true;
            foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) 
            {
                stack.Push(childNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work good, although only when the checkbox is checked, it does not fire the event. I have to click on the hyperlink in order for it to launch. Here is how it is set up,

Comment: <asp:TreeView ID="tv_WLG" runat="server"   OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="tv_WLG_TreeNodeCheckChanged"  ShowCheckBoxes="All" ></asp:TreeView>